# How to configure dynamic URL in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am configuring a dynamic url in my django project. I have followed the instructions provided on the net but it is not working.

urls.py in app

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^seci/<int:secn>', views.sect, name = 'sect'),
    url('sections/<str:secn>/', views.sections, name = 'sections'),
]
```

views.py in app

```
def sect(request,secn):
    print("secn:", secn)
    return HttpResponse("testing")

def sections(request, secn):
    print("secn:", secn)
    return HttpResponse(secn)
```

Django says, url not found. I don’t know what else to do.

Comment: You're mixing old and new style urls, use [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#path) instead of `url`

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.urls import path
# here is import of your views

urlpatterns = [
    path('seci/<int:secn>', views.sect, name='sect'),
    path('sections/<str:secn>', views.sections, name='sections'),
]
```

Comment: I am using an older version of django. Is it possible to make this work in the older version?

Answer (score 0):

Saw this in a video

```
url(r'^seci/(?P<secn>\w+)', views.sect, name = 'sect'),
url(r'sections/(?P<secn>\w+)/', views.sections, name = 'sections'),
```